# Error: The specified child already has a parent

Tags: java, android, layout, view

In my program I get this error on my emulator. **If I run this on my Razr MAXX it works?** It says that

```
10-28 19:38:27.935: E/AndroidRuntime(2268): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

The error occurs on this line: `layout.addView(mid)`

I believe it says that mid already has a parent, so I debugged with `ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mid.getParent();` and it returns null...

Can someone please lead me in the right direction?

Below is my class:

```
package com.example.draganddroptest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * @author Brandon Ling
 * 
 */
public class HoneycombView extends View {
    private Context context;
    private ViewGroup layout;
    private HexagonView top;
    private HexagonView topRight;
    private HexagonView topLeft;
    private HexagonView bot;
    private HexagonView botLeft;
    private HexagonView botRight;
    private HexagonView mid;
    private int radius;
    private PointF shift;
    private String color;
    private String[] colors;
    private int strokeWidth;

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param layout
     */
    public HoneycombView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, null, 0, null, null, attrs, 0);
    }

    public HoneycombView(Context context, ViewGroup layout, int radius, PointF shift, String color, AttributeSet attrs, int strokeWidth) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;

        if (attrs != null) { // probably sent via xml
            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.HoneycombView);
            this.radius = a.getInt(R.styleable.HoneycombView_radius, this.strokeWidth);
            this.shift = new PointF(a.getInt(R.styleable.HoneycombView_shiftX, 0), a.getInt(
                    R.styleable.HoneycombView_shiftY, 0));
            this.colors = a.getString(R.styleable.HoneycombView_hexColors).split("\\|");
            a.recycle();
        } else {
            this.layout = layout;
            this.radius = radius;
            this.shift = shift;
            this.color = color;
        }
        this.mid = new HexagonView(this.context, null, this.radius, this.shift, this.colors[0], 10);
        this.top = mid.addHexTop(colors[1]);
        this.topRight = mid.addHexTopRight(colors[2]);
        this.topLeft = mid.addHexTopLeft(colors[3]);
        this.bot = mid.addHexBot(colors[4]);
        this.botRight = mid.addHexBotRight(colors[5]);
        this.botLeft = mid.addHexBotLeft(colors[6]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        this.layout = (ViewGroup) this.getParent();
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mid.getParent();
        //parent.removeAllViews();
        layout.addView(mid);
        layout.addView(top);
        layout.addView(topRight);
        layout.addView(topLeft);
        layout.addView(bot);
        layout.addView(botRight);
        layout.addView(botLeft);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int height = (int) Math.ceil(this.bot.getMaxY()) + this.strokeWidth;
        int width = (int) Math.ceil(this.botRight.getMaxX()) + this.strokeWidth;
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You should not be doing layout in `onDraw()`

Comment: I'm trying to construct a View from other views (honeycomb made up of hexagons) http://depositphotos.com/1830169/stock-illustration-Honeycomb.html

Comment: Then make HoneycombView() a ViewGroup or **draw** the hexagons in `onDraw()`

Comment: I tried drawing the hexagons in onDraw, but I still get the error. I will try viewgroup. But, why does it work on my phone and not emulator?

Comment: `onDraw()` is called repeatedly by Android. The second call to `onDraw()` will throw this exception because each `View` is already added to the parent.

Comment: If you tried drawing in onDraw(), and you still got the error, then you have the same problem somewhere else in your code since it is not possible to get this exception unless you try to add a view to a view group.  The logcat will tell you exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `onDraw()` is called repeatedly by Android. The second call to `onDraw()` will throw this exception because each `View` is already added to the parent.
2. That said, as a rule, you never change the layout inside `onDraw()`. This method is for painting on the `Canvas` only. Even if you manage to fix this exception by calling `removeAllViews()` (as it looks like you might have tried), you will force Android to continuously measure and draw the layout again and again as views are removed and re-added.
3. You probably don't actually want to add your child views to the parent. If you want to add child views, you should add them as children of the `HoneyCombView`. To do this, you'll need to extend `ViewGroup` instead of `View`. And again, add the child views somewhere else, not in `onDraw()`.
4. Although adding child views to a `ViewGroup` will work, it's not very good for performance. Each child view you add to a layout slows the application. (See [Use Fewer Views](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2013/09/17/android-performance-bits-and-pieces-part-ii-use-fewer-views.html).) A much better alternative is to draw shapes directly onto the `Canvas` using (for example) `canvas.drawPath()`.